# Session information only updating after refresh

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I've just added logins to my site. I've adapted [this script](http://www.php-login.net/). My main header file contains the following php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
    $link = "loginform.php?logout";
    $text = "Log Out";
    echo '<a href="' . $link . ' "><div id="login">' . $text . '</div></a>';
}
else {
    $link = "loginform.php";
    $text = "Supplier Login";
    echo '<a href="' . $link . ' "><div id="login">' . $text . '</div></a>';
}
?>
```

The goal of this is obviously to make the div up the top right of my page display "login" if there is no user_name stored in the $_SESSION, and to display "logout" if there is information in the user_name $_SESSION.

This works perfectly fine except after logging in it will still display the login button until I refresh the page once. I assume this has something to do with the fact that the script uses includes for security purposes and does not refresh the entire page (including the header with the div/button) after a login. How can I get around this?

Comment: You should check to see if `$_SESSION['user_name']` is being set before this script is being ran. Otherwise at the end of your authentication script where you set the `$_SESSION` variables do a simple redirect `header("Location: /samepage");` and basically rerun that page.

Comment: Ended up adding the following code to my login page. 

    if (!isset($_GET['r'])) {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content= "0;URL=?r=1" />';
    }

Worked like a charm.

Comment: That's good and all put it's appreciably slower seeing as how an entire page has to be loaded, rendered and a new connection made before the user even begins to load the intended page. Handling the refresh server side is way faster and doesn't accrue extra bandwidth.